# Adicionar TAG HTML com CSS content

Tags: html, css, css3

É possível adicionar um TAG HTML através do CSS `content`?

```css
#teste{
   content: "<p>tag HTML inserida via CSS</p>";
}
```

```html
<div id="teste"></teste>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando after ou before tu podes adicionar algum conteúdo à tua tag e estilizá-la mas se usar tags dentro do content será interpretado literalmente, como texto.

```
#teste:before{
content: "<a href='http://link.com'>Era pra ser um link</a>";
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Conforme o nosso amigo Vitor André falou, será realmente interpretado como texto. O ideal é utilizar jquery para fazer injeção de html na página, utilizando "append" ou "prepend".